# Error al llamar un procedimiento almacenado(MariaDB) con parametro en Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, stored-procedure, mariadb

No he conseguido ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado con parámetro. Especificamente me sale este error:

**"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'getIngresosID(?)' at line 1 (SQL: getIngresosID(2))**

en el index paso el parametro de esta forma:

```
<a href="{{URL::action('CuentaController@show',$cue->idcuenta)}}">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                                Detalles
                            </button>
                        </a>
```

El procedimiento esta en MariaDB y es el siguiente:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getIngresosID`(in id int)
BEGIN
    select i.idingreso, i.fecha, i.tipo_comprobante, i.num_comprobante, i.impuesto, i.estado, p.nombres, sum(di.cantidad*di.precio_compra) as total
        from ingresos as i 
        join detalleingresos as di
        on i.idingreso=di.ingreso_id
        join personas as p
        on i.provedor_id=p.idpersona
        where i.idingreso=id
        group by i.idingreso, p.nombres, i.tipo_comprobante, i.num_comprobante, 
        i.impuesto, i.estado;
END
```

Las **tablas** son las siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En **laravel** llamo el procedimientos de esta manera:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Persona;
use App\Ingreso;
use App\DetalleIngreso;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use DB;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class IngresoController extends Controller
{
      public function show($id)
        {
            $ingreso=DB::select('getIngresosID"'. $id.'"');

            return view("compras.ingreso.show",["ingreso"=>$ingreso);
        }
}
```

He intentado de varias formas:

```
$ingreso=DB::select('getIngresosID(?)', array($id));

$ingreso=DB::select('getIngresosID ?', array($id));

$ingreso=DB::select('getIngresosID ?', $id);
```

Con las dos primeras me sale el mismo error pero en la ultima me notifica este error:

**"Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pro_laravel\crediPaisa**

Comment: mi caso es peor, tenía una db con mysql con muchas tablas y muchos procedimientos almacenados y al instalar la ultima version de xampp, supuestamente estable, viene con mariaDB en vez de mysql. se supone q maríaDB está pensado para simplemente ser 100% compatible con mysql, así que decidi importar la base de datos que tenía en mysql a mariaDB. la base de datos efectivamente se importa, pero con un pequeñito detalle...NINGÚN PROCEDIMIENTO SE IMPORTA... arroja el siguiente error: #1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100413.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He dado con la respuesta y funciona con laravel 9

```
DB::select('CALL getIngresosID(?)', array($id));
```